# Checkbox while applying Filters

Tags: forms, checkboxes, customer-experience

We are creating custom forms. The user can choose any type of field that he wants to. It can be a checkbox, dropdown, text, paragraph, etc. Customers can fill these application forms and the admin can see a list of all these filled forms.
Now, there is an option to filter the applications. The customer can apply a value to any field and filter based on it.

The checkbox field cannot be grouped. It's a standalone field.
While filtering, if the checkbox is enabled, it'll list all the applications that have that particular checkbox enabled.

But, how should it behave when the checkbox is disabled? Should it display everything or should it filter based on the values that have the checkbox value marked as false?
There is no way to remove the fields that apply on the filter. All fields on the form (except text fields) are visible as filters.

[image]

The Question is:
If 'Need Manager Approval' is checked, I'll list all the applications that have 'Need Manager Approval' as true.

If 'Need Manager Approval' is not checked. Should I list all the applications where 'Need Manager Approval' is unchecked or should I list all the applications irrespective of the value for 'Need Manager Approval'?

Comment: Hi Mino,
it is hard to understand the interaction and the problem here. Do you have a UI to show how the interaction works? What checkbox am I filtering on and why?

Comment: I think will be great to see a screenshot to better understand the issue here :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use a filter that shows all by default when no filter is applied?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/122916/when-to-use-a-filter-that-shows-all-by-default-when-no-filter-is-applied)

Comment: Yup. That's something i was expecting. The only difference is that the check boxes i have here are not grouped under a category like Price Range, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, how should it behave when the checkbox is disabled? Should it display everything or should it filter based on the values that have the checkbox value marked as false?

The problem is that no matter which logic you choose, you will always have some users that expect (and want) the other logic.

Therefore, the solution is that your filter options should allow for 3 states, not just the 2 values that can be selected:

- Manager Approval Needed
- Manager Approval Not Needed
- Any

I would suggest this is handled as either a dropdown or a set of radio buttons, where the default option is "Any" (no filter).

Comment: So, instead of checkbox should I be showing a dropdown in a filter?

Comment: @MinoDeRaj: I have updated my answer based on your question edit. Yes, you should use a drop down in the filter with the options I have listed in the answer.